# KIVY scroll view won't show anything just a blank screen

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, scrollview, kivymd

I created a stack layout with 100 buttons in it. This alone works but when I add the stack layout under scroll view layout nothing is displayed on the screen.[without using scroll view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG1IN.png)

[when scroll view is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG1IN.png)

**Python code**

```
from  kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView




class stacklayoutex(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(100):
            b=Button(text=str(i+1),size_hint=(None,None),size=(dp(100),dp(100)))
            self.add_widget(b)

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass
TheLabApp().run()
```

**KV file**

```
scrollviewex:

<scrollviewex@ScrollView>:
    stacklayoutex:
    size_hint: 1,None
    height:4000

<stacklayoutex>:
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems:

Your class names must begin with upper case. Not following this rule can cause syntax errors in your `kv`.
Also, indentation error in your `kv`, it should be:

```
Scrollviewex:

<Scrollviewex@ScrollView>:
    Stacklayoutex:
        size_hint: 1,None
        height:4000

<Stacklayoutex>:
```